# Cannot read properties of null (reading '_id')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

so i have 2 buttons one delete and an edit, i only want the one who commented to be able to delete and edit his post, the delete button is working but i didn't test the edit one because i kept on getting error,
My problem is it was working before, only the authorized and the one who commented could view the post, but i went back to do some css and now keep on getting "Cannot read properties of null (reading '_id')"

```html
function PostItem({el}) {
     const dispatch = useDispatch()
     const history= useHistory()
     const [text, setText]=useState("")
     const auth =  useSelector(state=> state.UserReducer.auth)
     const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
      e.preventDefault();
      dispatch(AddComment(el._id, {text}));
    
    
     };


     useEffect(() => {
  //  dispatch(Getpost(el._id))
  dispatch(current())
     }, [])
     const reducerUser = useSelector(state => state.UserReducer.user)
    

    return(
        
      <section className="dark">
      <div className="container-p">
       
        <article className="newPost">
         
          <div className="post-head">
            <h6 className="post-name">{el.name}</h6>
            <div className="post-body">
              <time dateTime="date-post">
                 <i className="date-post" /><Moment>"YYYY/MM/DD" </Moment> 
              </time>
            </div>
            <div className="post-text" />
            <p>{el.text}</p>
            
            {auth  &&  reducerUser._id == el.user &&
<div>
             <button onClick={()=>{dispatch(DeletePost(el._id))}}>
               Delete Post
             </button> 
             <button onClick={()=>{dispatch(EditPost(el._id))}}>EDIT
             </button>
              </div>
            }
            
            
            </div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <textarea   value={text} onChange={(e)=>setText(e.target.value)}   rows="2" cols="100" >
              </textarea>
              
              <button className='btn' type="submit" > add comment</button>
              <p>
                {el.comments.map(el=> el.text && el.text )}
              </p>
            </form>
        </article>
      </div></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Null Propagation operator changing the reducerUser._id for reducerUser?._id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in your `el` object on each button component to prevent the error and inside your store methods validate if the value is null just ignore it like this:

```html
function PostItem({el}) {
     const dispatch = useDispatch()
     const history= useHistory()
     const [text, setText]=useState("")
     const auth =  useSelector(state=> state.UserReducer.auth)
     const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
      e.preventDefault();
      dispatch(AddComment(el._id, {text}));
    
    
     };


     useEffect(() => {
  //  dispatch(Getpost(el._id))
  dispatch(current())
     }, [])
     const reducerUser = useSelector(state => state.UserReducer.user)
    

    return(
        
      <section className="dark">
      <div className="container-p">
       
        <article className="newPost">
         
          <div className="post-head">
            <h6 className="post-name">{el.name}</h6>
            <div className="post-body">
              <time dateTime="date-post">
                 <i className="date-post" /><Moment>"YYYY/MM/DD" </Moment> 
              </time>
            </div>
            <div className="post-text" />
            <p>{el.text}</p>
            
            {auth  &&  reducerUser?._id == el.user &&
<div>
             <button onClick={()=>{dispatch(DeletePost(el?._id))}}>
               Delete Post
             </button> 
             <button onClick={()=>{dispatch(EditPost(el?._id))}}>EDIT
             </button>
              </div>
            }
            
            
            </div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <textarea   value={text} onChange={(e)=>setText(e.target.value)}   rows="2" cols="100" >
              </textarea>
              
              <button className='btn' type="submit" > add comment</button>
              <p>
                {el.comments.map(el=> el.text && el.text )}
              </p>
            </form>
        </article>
      </div></section>
```